# Dimension of $\{X\in M_n|AX=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A \in M_n[\mathbb{R}], \operatorname{rank}(A)=r \le n$ and subspace $W=\{X\in M_n[\mathbb{R}]|AX=0\}$. Find $\dim W$.

I know that if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\dim\{Ax =0\}=n-\operatorname{rank}(A)$. Assume that $\ker A=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-r}\}$

so if $X \in M_n[\mathbb{R}]$ and  $AX=0$, each column of $X$ should be a combination of vectors in $\ker A$ but I don't know which dimension it has since I cannot imagine what a basis for $X$.

Comment: Note that $AX = 0$ **iff** $A (X e_k) = 0$ for $k=1,...,n$. In other words, a matrix $X$ is in the null space of the operator $X \mapsto AX$ **iff** $Ax_k = 0$ for each column $x_k$ of $X$. That is, $n$ copies of the null space of $A$.

Comment: so $\dim W = n(n-r)$ right?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks for helping me :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been discussed in the comments, this null space is the direct product of $n$ copies of the column null space of dimension $n-r$ and thus has dimension $n(n-r)$.